# DevOps linux agents - Run as admin

Tags: linux, azure-devops

I have setup linux agents following the documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops

When I run some scripts on devOps pipelines on these agents I get the permission denied error.

What is the DevOps way of handling this permission?

Answer (score 1):

Whether you [run the agent as a service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/v2-linux?view=azure-devops#run-as-a-systemd-service) or interactively, you can choose which computer account you use to run the agent. (Note that this is different from the credentials that you use when you register the agent with Azure Pipelines ) The choice of agent account **depends solely on the needs of the tasks running in your build and deployment jobs**.

For example, to run tasks that use some authentication to access an external service, you must run the agent using an account that has access to that service.

According to your description, seems the build service account is lacking of permission. Make sure you have given that account enough permission. Or you couldrun the agent service as root `sudo ./svc.sh install root`